# Cannot find name Promise

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-promise, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am having trouble using Promise in angular2. I have imported all files as suggested by angular docs. But get the error "Cannot find name Promise". Below is my code:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class StorefrontService {
    private sfUrl = 'app/storefront/storefront.component.json';  // URL to mock json
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getSfItems(): Promise<any[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.sfUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }
    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }
}
```

Is the Promise object needs to be imported from somewhere? I tried importing from rxjs library but it did not work.

```
import { Promise } from 'rxjs/Promise';
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you get the error in your browser or in your ide

Comment: I get this in IDE( VS Code )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the import section:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

`this.http.get(...)` will return an observable which can return a promise by adding `toPromise()` like your did in your code. futher you have not to import anything else for promise since it is a default class in ES6.

see also:

- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ksBjyCgwuiEUGn9h2NYQGtmQkP5N9HbehMBgaxMtwfs/edit#heading=h.adsv85z7smgj
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

hope this helps.

Comment: Hey.. I tried but it still gives same error in IDE. One more thing. In my tsconfig.json I have target set to ES5..

Comment: Set it to ES6 and ignore the error, it will compile fine